# Only allow certain hosts to access my Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I would like to basically whitelist/blacklist my firebase https function, so that only certain IPs can access it.
Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43570358/restrict-access-to-google-cloud-functions-to-a-given-network, https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/using-vpc-service-controls, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62329759/limit-firebase-cloud-function-to-ip-addresses